# Rails/Devise - NoMethodError (undefined method new_with_session' for #<Class:0x2b2a4e34>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nomethoderror

I've got a very strange issue, which arose quite unexpectedly during testing/bugfixing on my production environment (FreeBSD/Apache/Passenger/MySQL):

```
$ tail log/production.log

Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 192.168.5.7 at 2011-08-06 21:37:53 +0400
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as
  SQL (1.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
Completed   in 15ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `new_with_session' for #<Class:0x2b2a4e34>):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:71:in `build_resource'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:8:in `new'
```

User management is organized with Devise gem. Sign in page is OK, Sign up page throws this error.

Everything went very well till I changed one of the fields (not related to Devise) in the database (changed type int -> bigint), and uploaded db/schema.rb and db/migrations/20110412205837_rename_files.rb. Then I reset the database with

```
$ rake db:setup RAILS_ENV='production'
```

, restarted the app with

```
$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```

, tried to sign up as a new user - and then saw that unhappy error page and the NoMethodError report in log file. I didn't change the devise section in models/user.rb file (OK, I did, but I also restarted the app after that and all was fine).

Here is my models/user.rb devise section:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
```

I am sure that this is a miserable issue, maybe a mistype of something else, a very little nasty bug, but I can't imagine what it can be... I've been looking for it for two days and I don't know where else to look. Please people help!

I've already tried the following:

- Returned to the previous version of db/schema.rb, and reset the DB;
- Downgraded to the previous version of the whole rails app;
- Moved app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb to app/controllers/devise
  and app/controllers/registrations directories;
- Downgraded Devise gem from 1.1.7 to 1.1.2;
- Restarted Passenger, Apache, and the whole FreeBSD;
- looked in the /var/log/httpd.log and /var/log/httpd_error.log files;
- recreated the database;
- checked and recreated MySQL users and grants;
- Bundle update;

Nothing helps...

What else can I do? Why did this problem appear?

Thanks VERY MUCH to any input in advance!

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else experiencing this pain, there is a chance you were as silly as me and forgot include:

```
# app/models/user.b
devise :registerable
```

in your model.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the owner of the whole app directory to www

```
$ chown -R www data
```

(didn't help at that moment though)

Then, updated previously downgraded (during the bug hunt) Devise to the latest 1.4.2 version with

```
$ bundle update
```

Then it all helped. I think (though I don't understand why) that the owner of the files should be the same owner as the owner of httpd process (check with `$ ps aux | grep httpd` ).

Hopefuly it will help someone